# Adding Chime Effect in Adobe Audition CC 2018

Tags: adobe-audition

Some time ago I was poking around in Audition's Effects Rack. In the process, I ran across a subtle effect that adds a light chime sound to the selection. I believe I've gone back through the entire rack again, but haven't been able to locate it. Are you aware of where this effect is and what it's called?

Answer (score 1):

I found it after some more searching in the buried parts of the Effects section. Under Filter and EQ > Notch Filter, several of the presets add a chime effect. Basically anything under the presets that start with numbers add various musical effects.